How can I uncheck "None" when I check other choices?
How can I make my checkbox dynamic?
so currently, I have a 3 checkbox here

What happens here is when I click, tcet and others, and then I click the none, it will uncheck the two.

But the problem, I'm trying to solve, is how can I uncheck none, when I click the other two. example , i click the none and then click tcet. The none should be uncheck.
I'm currently using react-hook-form and shadcn
<FormField
                  control={form.control}
                  name="does_have_assistance"
                  render={() => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <div className="mb-4">
                        <FormLabel className="text-base">
                          Tech Assitance
                        </FormLabel>
                      </div>
                      {does_have_assistance_choice.map((item) => (
                        <FormField
                          key={item.id}
                          control={form.control}
                          name="does_have_assistance"
                          render={({ field }) => {
                            return (
                              <FormItem
                                key={item.id}
                                className="flex flex-row items-start space-x-3 space-y-0"
                              >
                                <FormControl>
                                  <Checkbox
                                    checked={field.value?.includes(item.id)}
                                    onCheckedChange={(checked) => {
                                      if (item.id === 'none' && checked) {
                                        field.onChange(['none']);
                                      } else if (item.id !== 'none' && checked) {
                                        field.onChange(
                                          ['none'].includes(field.value) ? 
                                          [...field.value.filter(value => value !== 'none'), item.id] :
                                          [...field.value, item.id]
                                        );
                                      } else {
                                        // If deselecting a checked option, remove it from the array
                                        field.onChange(
                                          field.value?.filter((value: any) => value !== item.id)
                                        );
                                      }
                                    }}
                                  />
                                </FormControl>

                                <FormLabel className="font-normal">
                                  {item.label}
                                </FormLabel>
                              </FormItem>
                            );
                          }}
                        />
                      ))}
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                  )}
                />

Choices.ts
export const does_have_assistance_choice = [
  {
    id:'none',
    label:"None"
  },
  {
    id: "tcet",
    label: "TCET",
  },
  {
    id: "others",
    label: "Others",
  },
];


Hi I have just changed your onChangeChecked logic
You can try this logic here.
onCheckedChange={(checked) => {
  if (item.id === 'none' && checked) {
     / If "none" is selected, clear all other selections
     field.onChange(['none']);
  } else if (item.id !== 'none' && checked) {
      // If another option is selected, remove "none" and add the option
           field.onChange(
               field.value.includes('none')
                   ? [item.id]
                   : [...field.value, item.id]);
                      } else {
                        field.onChange(
                          field.value?.filter((value) => value !== item.id)
                        );
                      }
                    }}

